# Dúvida para inserir registro com chave estrangeira. ENTITY FRAMEWORK

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Sou iniciante (bemmmm iniciante) em programação, e tenho um case para desenvolver, que seria um Crud, utilizando asp.net (C#) e Entity Framework. Criei um formulário simples de cadastro de contato, onde existe um campo de nome de empresa. Tabela contato e tabela Empresa, onde existe um campo de ligação entre as duas. No cadastro eu informo o nome da empresa. Como faço para que ao gravar esse formulário, seja primeiro inserido o registro na tabela empresa, e depois na de contato seja colocado no campo de chave estrangeira o código da empresa?

Tentei fazer algo assim, mas não consegui resolver até o momento

```
protected void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (ModelConexao db = new ModelConexao())
        {

            Contato contato = new Contato()
            {
                nome = txtNome.Text,
                telefone = txtTelefone.Text,
                email = txtEmail.Text,
                idEmpresa = db.Empresa
                 .Where(c => c.nome == txtEmpresa.Text)
                 .Select(c => c.codigo)
            };                          

            db.Contato.Add(contato);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        this.DataBind()
```

A ideia é que ao cadastrar insira o registro na tabela secundaria (empresa), e busque o código (IdEmpresa) da empresa para salvar na de Contato, fazendo a ligação deste campo.

Answer (score 1):

Quando usamos o *Entity*, não podemos setar o campo `ID` com o valor da tabela primária, devemos utilizar em forma de objetos.
Faça uma `query` e torne uma variável em objeto, e seta seu objeto `empresa` da classe `Contato`,  como no exemplo abaixo:

```
    using (ModelConexao db = new ModelConexao())
    {
     var empresa = db.Empresa.Where(c => c.nome == txtEmpresa.Text).FirstOrDefault();

        Contato contato = new Contato()
        {
            nome = txtNome.Text,
            telefone = txtTelefone.Text,
            email = txtEmail.Text,
            Empresa = empresa
        };                          

        db.Contato.Add(contato);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    this.DataBind()
```

Comment: Nesse teu exemplo, está buscando apenas da tabela de empresa né? No meu caso, quero que seja cadastrada a empresa, e dai com o código idEmpresa gerado (automaticamente), eu use no Contato. Não sei se consegui explicar melhor.

Comment: Você pode passar o objeto empresa direto no contato que o entity irá inserir, ai não precisa fazer um query.

Comment: Complementando: é orientado fazer como o exemplo acima, fazendo query, pois o entity irá criar um hash pro objeto e não irá dar conflito futuramente para inserir.    Conselho: faça a inserção da empresa, faça uma query e busca a empresa, e depois faz como o exemplo acima, insere o contato passando o objeto empresa